# RabbitMQ delayed message not working

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange

I am trying to use delayed exchange plugin, but somehow its not working for me and message are received without delay.

I tried following things :

a) enabled rabbitmq_delayed_message_exchange successfully and restarted rabbitmq server on ubuntu-16.04.

b) Declaring exchange

```
Map<String,Object> props = new HashMap<String,Object>();

props.put("x-delayed-type", "direct");

this.automationExchange = new DirectExchange(exchangeName,true,false, props);
```

c) Pushing message as

```
DefaultClassMapper typeMapper = QueueUtils.classMapper;
typeMapper.setDefaultType(type);

Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = QueueUtils.converter;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
converter.setClassMapper(typeMapper);

RabbitTemplate template = AMQPRabbitMQTemplate.getAMQPTemplate();
template.setMessageConverter(converter);

template.convertAndSend(routingKey, message, new MessagePostProcessor() {

    @Override
    public Message postProcessMessage(Message m) throws AmqpException {
        m.getMessageProperties().setDelay(delayMiliSeconds);
        m.getMessageProperties().setDeliveryMode(MessageDeliveryMode.PERSISTENT);
        return m;
    }
});
```

Now when i am printing message

```
public void onMessage(Message message, Channel channel) throws Exception{
    System.out.println(message.getMessageProperties().getDelay());
    channel.basicAck(message.getMessageProperties().getDeliveryTag(), false);
}
```

It is printing null for getDelay, which ideally should be negative of set value as per https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq.

Please let me know if i am doing something wrong.
I am using 1.6.8.RELEASE version for spring-amqp and spring-rabbit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to avoid unexpected propagation of headers from an inbound message to an outbound message, certain headers for inbound messages are provided by `MessageProperties.getReceived...` methods.

In this case, the header is in `MessageProperties.getReceivedDelay()`.

You also need `setDelayed(true)` on `automationExchange` before declaring it with the admin.

I presume you have set the exchange as the default in the `RabbitTemplate` too.

Comment: Thanks Gary it worked after setting  setDelayed(true).